missing storage raid / lvm after updating ubuntu server 22.04 5.15 to 6.2.0, where do I start
I'm missing a 4 drive raid, I wasn't super sure how it was set up really, I updated the kernel for specific nvidia drivers to 6.2.0. I can see the drives in lsblk, and it looks like they still have their partitions. I only see a volume group for the OS drive. What can I do to figure out how to resolve this. I only vaguely recall creating physical and software volumes / groups. lsblk used to show a similar dev mapper on the four drives.
NAME                      MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
loop0                       7:0    0  55.7M  1 loop /snap/core18/2796
loop1                       7:1    0  55.7M  1 loop /snap/core18/2812
loop2                       7:2    0  63.9M  1 loop /snap/core20/2105
loop3                       7:3    0  63.9M  1 loop /snap/core20/2182
loop4                       7:4    0  91.8M  1 loop /snap/lxd/23991
loop5                       7:5    0  91.8M  1 loop /snap/lxd/24061
loop6                       7:6    0  40.4M  1 loop /snap/snapd/20671
loop7                       7:7    0  39.1M  1 loop /snap/snapd/21184
sda                         8:0    0   2.7T  0 disk 
├─sda1                      8:1    0   2.7T  0 part 
└─sda9                      8:9    0     8M  0 part 
sdb                         8:16   0   2.7T  0 disk 
├─sdb1                      8:17   0   2.7T  0 part 
└─sdb9                      8:25   0     8M  0 part 
sdc                         8:32   0   2.7T  0 disk 
├─sdc1                      8:33   0   2.7T  0 part 
└─sdc9                      8:41   0     8M  0 part 
sdd                         8:48   0   2.7T  0 disk 
├─sdd1                      8:49   0   2.7T  0 part 
└─sdd9                      8:57   0     8M  0 part 
sde                         8:64   1 232.9G  0 disk 
├─sde1                      8:65   1 232.8G  0 part 
└─sde2                      8:66   1    32M  0 part 
nvme0n1                   259:0    0 931.5G  0 disk 
└─nvme0n1p1               259:1    0 931.5G  0 part /Nextcloud
nvme1n1                   259:2    0 232.9G  0 disk 
├─nvme1n1p1               259:3    0     1G  0 part /boot/efi
├─nvme1n1p2               259:4    0   1.5G  0 part /boot
└─nvme1n1p3               259:5    0 230.3G  0 part 
  └─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv 253:0    0 230.3G  0 lvm  /


Is there an /etc/mdadm.conf file? Does mdadm --examine --scan discover any RAID devices?

You mention "updated the kernel for specific nvidia drivers to 6.2.0" but don't specify what nvidia driver you updated to 6.2.  If you are talking instead about the 6.2 linux kernel, that was from 23.04 which is EOL with that kernel now unsupported and unpatched for security flaws; but was the 6.2 reference related to a nvidia driver, if so which?

@steeldriver I got 0 output from the mdadm command and that file doesn't exist.

@guiverc I updated the kernel from 5.15 to 6.2.0 as a part of this nvidia installation instructions

If you read those instructions; they no longer directly apply (for security reasons) as per Ubuntu 22.04.z (z <= 3) LTS  where Ubuntu 22.04 is now 22.04.4 (z is not <=3 as 4>3)...   I hope you plan on keeping your system offline! as your following instructions that are out of date as 6.2 kernel is no longer supported (Ubuntu 23.04 is EOL)

... so I guess whatever you had it wasn't md raid?

@steeldriver, I think it could've been after setting up the physcial and logical volumes, unfortunately I've done a different type of raid with each system through the years so I don't have experience doing the same thing twice and it all blurs together making it hard to remember.

@guiverc I'm happy to take your advice and update to a different kernel, I'm on 22.4.4 now and ubuntu shows that as LTS, you said LTS, so I'm confused on how 23.04 is EOL, I don't think you're saying to update to something higher than ubuntu 23.04 but that's how I read it.

Ubuntu's GA (ie. unique kernel) is 5.15... The HWE kernel stack updates from later releases, which was the 5.19 from 22.10, 6.2 from 23.04, and currently is 6.5 from 23.10.. but will be 6.8 from 24.04 in the future & remain there (ie. GA stack from next LTS).  The 6.2 kernel from 23.04 is EOL & unsupported including on 22.04 LTS as HWE is now 6.5 from 23.10. For more details you can read https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack

@guiverc okay, I read that and some other things, I get it now, LTS is LTS, in between versions need to be the latest, cause they're not LTS. I guess I'll update to 23.10 here. I feel like I should fix the raid first, as I'm worried the update could somehow put me in a worse state.

Sorry no, you're using a 22.04 LTS system but using a unsupported kernel that came from 23.04.  The GA (5.15) kernel is unique to 22.04, and some media (eg. initial flavors & Server) install with that... however Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Desktop (and flavors of 22.04.2 & newer) default to HWE which updates from later releases... where 22.04.3 used the 6.2 kernel from 23.04, but upgraded to 6.5 from 23.10 before 23.04 went EOL as part of 22.04.4 upgrades.  Your system is LTS (ie. 22.04) but supported kernels for 22.04.4 are 5.15 (GA never changes) OR 6.5 (from 23.10)..  (or OEM stacks)

If your system is used offline, using an unsupported or unpatched (for security issues) won't be a problem, as only the GA (5.15) or current HWE (6.5 as we're currently 22.04.4) get security fixes.. thus if security matters to you (ie. you're online) I suggest using a supported kernel stack (GA = 5.15, HWE currently 6.5, other OEM options too).
